# Apply timezone to timestamp

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have an api which is currently returning a UTC timestamp in the following format

```
2022-09-11T14:29:55.343Z
```

And In my frontend application, if I call .toUTCString() I get the following

```
Sun, 11 Sep 2022 14:29:55 GMT
```

Which is nice and “human readable”

From the same api, I am can also get a “timezoneOffset” which I need to apply to this if it is present, and that comes back as a string in the following format

"+02"

(note that this can also come in minus formats also)

My first reaction is to substring the first element of the above to find out if it’s a + or -, and then perform the relevant operation with the “number” part.

Very roughly, that would give me something like this (with rawDate being the value at the top of the question, and the + and number being worked out from the timezoneOffset value)

```
const newDate = new Date(rawDate.setHours(rawDate.getHours() + number)).toUTCString())
```

which will render out the following

```
Sun, 11 Sep 2022 16:29:55 GMT
```

The time is now obviously correct, but as this is a modified version of the UTC timestamp, the time zone hasn’t really been applied.

is there a built in way to “apply” a time zone to a timestamp which is in UTC format, or is there a library that I can use with the above vales? I started to look into moment.js but a lot of the posts around that seem to suggest it is now deprecated, and it feels a little overkill as my application only has a few places where data formatting is needed.

Comment: `+02` is not useful ... what if the timezone is not a full hour away from GMT, like india - anyway ... timezones are complicated ... does +02 mean east or west?? If you `.toUTCString` of course the result is in GMT

Comment: What output are you actually looking for?

Comment: Why isn't the offset applied to the timestamp already? If it's because it's a user setting of their preferred timezone or something like that, then just storing `+02` for that user preference is pointless, since *offsets* change throughout the year for some timezones. The timezone `Europe/Berlin` for instance is sometimes `+01:00` and sometimes `+02:00`. That's why you'd need to store `Europe/Berlin` for user preferences.

Comment: for timezones a full hours away from GMT, you can use Intl.DateTimeFormat with a timeZone of `Etc/GMTxxx` ... where xxx can be +1, -2, +4 etc

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat for more info

Comment: Thank you - Intl.DateTimeFormat looks like it will do what I need for now but I agree "+02" is not useful. As it's an internal api I'll reach out to the dev and see if we can come up with something better

Comment: @JaromandaX—but it doesn't support part hours like GMT+5:30 and the sign is opposite. So for a place that is UTC+10 the *etc* equivalent is Etc/GMT-10 (for POSIX compliance, apparently).

Comment: @RobG I did mention the limitation. Also. It's unclear to me what the op actually wants to do